# How to draw a String to the window with OpenGL?

Tags: java, opengl

I'm creating a game but I have one problem: how can I draw text to the screen, as I want to print something every time the player picks up something or gets hurt. I already know the drawString() function for Graphics, but I am not sure if that is OK if I am using OpenGL. Is there a method from OpenGL that lets me easily print text to the screen?

Comment: Afaik OGL does not come with a font-drawing spec. I rember having read of a library that fits with the OGL interface, but I'm not sure about its name. Anyway, you could do your own drawing using a font-library like FreeType.

Comment: Well I would like to keep it using only the OpenGL libraries. I cant actually use drawString now cause its not a JFrame or Panel, but a OpenGL window. :/. But whats FreeType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenGL there is no function / method you can call to render text to the screen.

You have two choices: either 1) use a library; or 2) roll your own, creating your own calls to render text to the display.

1)  There are a number of different libraries out there that you could use to render text to the display; however the most obvious and accessible to you is within GLUT. There are two calls within that you could use:

```
glutBitmapString() and glutStrokeString()
```

The first of these will render text to the display in what I guess could be referred to as a 2d manner (looking like it's pasted right of the display). The latter with display 3d text.

You can refer to

```
http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/docs/api.php
```

for API references.

2)  You could create a function / method that renders character textures to the display using the standard OpenGL functions, or you could potentially use stencil buffers using calls to glDrawPixels() to generate the characters.

I haven't tried these: I'm just thinking off the top of my head so you're mileage may vary. Good luck.

Comment: thanks, I already have a different way of doing it, but this is really good too!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no method in OpenGL for easily printing text. You must either use one of the libraries that exist for this purpose or you must write it yourself.