# Draw a String to the Window with OpenGL in Java

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to draw a String to the window with OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143344/how-to-draw-a-string-to-the-window-with-opengl)

Im creating a simple 2D game and have run into a problem. I dont know how to display text to the screen while using OpenGL. I cant use the Graphics drawString() method because my window is an LWJGL window, not a JFrame.

Comment: A relevant but outdated site describing text rendering in OpenGL can be found [here](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/features/fontsurvey/)

Comment: OK, that is way to far above me... All I really want to do is display a simple, 2D text String to the screen

Comment: @CMP6LG OpenGL is a very low level library. It doesn't have the concept of drawing strings. It let's you draw triangles in numerous fashions, and that's basically it.

Answer (score 0):

[GLUT](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) has the facility to do what you want, which I'd recommend using, but you can also try using `glFontTextOut` with `glFontBegin` and `glFontEnd` enclosing, e.g:

```
glFontBegin(font);
glScalef(10.0, 10.0, 10.0);
glFontTextOut("Testing", 5, 5, 0);
glFontEnd();
```

Comment: How exactly would I use glFontTextOut? And thanks for responding quickly!

Comment: I haven't used it myself I'm afraid, this is just a bit of research to help out. Hopefully someone who has will see and be able to expand on it but there's a starting point for you at least!

Comment: Ah, my bad, turns out glFont is also an external library. See:
http://students.cs.byu.edu/~bfish/glfontdl.php

Comment: I'd still recommend using GLUT though, it is used so frequently by so many that it seems like part of the core library.

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl 

Actually that's wrong. GLUT is really just something to create examples and small throwaway programs, it's not really suited for "real" programs.