# Rendering text with Slick2D inside a LWJGL window?

Tags: java, text, lwjgl, slick2d

How would I render a basic string using Slick2D inside a window created with Display.Create() from LWJGL?

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do that, but there are libraries you can use for that. Look here for more info: [How to draw a String to the window with OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143344/how-to-draw-a-string-to-the-window-with-opengl)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should use Slick2d's `UnicodeFont` class.

With `UnicodeFont`, you can easily draw text in different colors to the screen.

To initialize:

```
UnicodeFont uf = null;
try {
    uf = new UnicodeFont("path/to/font", <size>, <bold>, <italic>);
    uf.getEffects().add(new ColorEffect(java.awt.Color.white)); // set the default color to white
    uf.addAsciiGlyphs();
    uf.loadGlyphs(); // load glyphs from font file
} catch (SlickException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

To draw text to the screen:

```
uf.drawString(<x>, <y>, <text>);
```

Be sure to  add this code to your OpenGL initialization:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

This ensures that this won't happen:

[image: oh no!]

Also, a similar problem will happen if `GL_DEPTH_TEST` is enabled. To fix this, disable `GL_DEPTH_TEST` while drawing text to the screen.

Full working font drawing program:

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.UnicodeFont;
import org.newdawn.slick.font.effects.ColorEffect;

public class TextDrawing {
    static UnicodeFont uf = null;


    public static void initGL() {
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, 640, 480, 0, 1, -1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void initFont(int size, boolean bold, boolean italic) {
        try {
            uf = new UnicodeFont("path/to/font.ttf", size, bold, italic);
            uf.addAsciiGlyphs();
            uf.getEffects().add(new ColorEffect(java.awt.Color.white));
            uf.loadGlyphs();
        } catch (SlickException e) {

        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(640, 480));
            Display.setTitle("Text Drawing!");
            Display.setResizable(false);
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {

        }

        initGL();
        initFont(100, false, false);

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {

            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            uf.drawString(10, 10, "Sweet Text");

            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);
        }

        System.exit(0);

    }
}
```

This produces:

[image: sweet text]

You will need to provide a font file.